# confidence level in non nested models

Tags: maximum-likelihood, confidence-interval

I have 7 non nested models: I use the Akaike method to see which one best describes the data.

If the models were nested I would use the likelihood ratio test: this woluld also automatically give me information on the confidence level: how can I do the same in my case?

Answer (score 0):

I think I resolved the problem using the Vuong cleseness test.

References:
[wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vuong%27s_closeness_test) and [the article](http://www.jstor.org/stable/1912557)